# How to find the second occurance of the amount 300 in the table

Tags: mysql

This is the table structure:

```
ID  Name        Amount  
1   AAA         500
2   BBB         100
3   CCC         300
4   DDD         300
5   EEE         200
6   FFF         300
7   GGG         500
```

How can I fetch 4th row based upon a condition of amount column?

Comment: What condition? Give more details, please by updating your question.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What do you expect as the result? Only the fourth row or any amount of rows, but including the fourth? What is specific about this row?

Comment: Here the task is to fetch the 4th column by applying any condition on amount column, I am asking how can I fetch second occurrence of the amount 300?

Comment: Research keywords `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: `fetch the 4th column` .. you mean 4th row? Don't use "column" and "row" interchangeably, they are different.

Comment: `I am asking how can I fetch second occurrence of the amount 300`... then why didn't you say so before? Anyway what version of mysql do you have?

Comment: Can you make up your mind, please? You either want to fetch the fourth row, _or_ you want to fetch the second row where the amount is 300. Both are two massively different things, that need different approaches. Just because the end result would happen to be the same here, doesn’t mean those selection operations were anywhere close to the same to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Second row where the amount is 300

Comment: *find the second occurance of the amount 300 in the table* `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE amount = 300 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1,1` - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37ae1ee21e3475cc5dbc17490b91623a

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by "second row where the amount is 300"? There are three rows with that amount, which one would be the one you prefer to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a specific answer only for the above table try:

```
 select * from *your_table_name* where amount = 300 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

Helpful [Link](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/limit/) about the Limit and Offset

***EDIT***
Explanation:

1. I use amount equal to 300 to keep only the rows that have this
   Amount
2. I have order the table ascending by id to use limit and offset. With Limit 1 returned only one row and with offset 1 is skipping the first row.

Comment: You have selected the 6th row. Test your code before posting an answer.

Comment: After the edit, you have selected the 3rd row. Once again, *test* before you post.

Comment: Thanks , i fix my mistake

Comment: Fix: `LIMIT 1,1` is correct, chooses `DDD`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where amount > 100 limit 3,1
```

this will fetch only the 4th record

Comment: No this is fetching 5th record

Comment: what is your sql query?

Comment: select * from customer where amount > 100 limit 3,1

Comment: Why `> 100`? I agree that the question is vague, but a more accurate specification has been established in the comments.

Comment: can you tell me the id of the fetched record?

Comment: @Shailendra using your query its fetching ID 5 or the 5th row

Comment: What's not clear about your query returning the 5th row? You're offsetting the first three values greater than 100 (rows 1, 3 and 4) and then fetching the next one.

Comment: then my query is correct, you asked for 4th row based on condition on amount column,  **select * from customer where amount > 100** run this query then you will get all the records and the 4th row will have the id 5 because id 2 will be skipped so you'll get id 1,3,4,5,6,7 and id 5 is the 4th row of the result and if you add **limit 3,1** means it'll select only id 5 record but if you want to fetch id 4 record based on amount condition then your query will be like **select * from customer where id = 4 and amount > 100**

Comment: @El_Vanja because he asked 4th row that's why i'm skipping first 3 records returned by query